# Error including one xslt to another

Tags: xslt

I have two xslt. one is included in other. but I am getting error in including the xslt.

## Main.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999`enter code here`/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:include href="branch.xslt"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Main.xslt* and *branch.xslt* , both available in same location.

> Error: 
>      I/O error reported by XML parser processing
>        file:/D:/workspaces/proj/removals.xslt: D:\workspaces\proj\removals.xslt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Can anyone suggest/guide where I am missing, please?

Comment: Isn't the processor complaining about some `removals.xslt` and not about `Main.xslt` or `branch.xslt`?

Comment: Is "removals.xslt" referenced inside of "branch.xslt"?

Comment: You should show us the content of `removals.xslt` as well.

Comment: And `branch.xslt` as well. Where is `removals.xslt` included?

Comment: Sorry for my miss-info. here, removals.xslt is same as the branch.xslt (typo). here is the branch.xslt.
 
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="abc" />
 <xsl:template match="xyz" />
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I think you should edit and rewrite the question with all the appropriate file names ... you have used main.xslt, branch.xslt, removals.xslt ... I do not think anyone can unwind it without you rewriting the text of your question with appropriate names and included files.